# Creating a javascript cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am attempting to create a cookie. I suspect that my cookie isnt saving or being retrieved properly. What am I doing wrong?

I tried 2 methods to save this cookie:

1. Cookie gets saved in this function:

   ```
   function(config) {
       var config_copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(config));
       setCookie('key',config_copy);
   }
   ```
2. Use setCookie();

   ```
   function(config) {
       var config_copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(config));
       setCookie();
   }
   ```

Then trigger this function:

```
function setCookie(key,config_copy){
    document.cookie = key + "=" + config_copy;
    console.log("cookie saved");
    console.log(config_copy);
}
```

`console.log(config_copy);` returns `undefined` in the console.

How would I correctly save the value of `config_copy` into a JavaScript cookie?

Comment: If you want to check your cookies you can open up your developer tools and either inspect the value in `document.cookie` by typing that in console. A question, in method 2 how would you expect the arg's `key, config_copy` to be defined in your `setCookie` function if you don't pass them?

Comment: how would you recommend I pass them in method 2?

Comment: by doing `setCookie("config", config_copy)`

Comment: http://davidbcalhoun.com/2009/passing-data-to-functions-in-javascript/ if you have to ask you really need to read a basic tutorial on functions in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse()` returns an object, not a JSON string. You should put the JSON string into the cookie, not the result of `JSON.parse`.

```
function saveConfig(config) {
    var config_copy = JSON.stringify(config);
    setCookie("key", config_copy);
}
```

Otherwise, you'll just set the cookie to `[Object object]`.

Answer (score 1):

[`Document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Syntax) only accepts [primitive values](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-primitive-value), if you pass an object it calls [`Object.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) which returns `[ object Object ]`.

You have too options for storing an object in cookie form.

1. #### Multiple cookies from an object's properties

   If you want to make a cookie out of each property of an object, you have to loop through the object and create a cookie out of each property.

   ```js
   var saveConfig = function(config) {
       var cookies = [];
       for(var i in config)
           cookies.push(document.cookie = i + '=' + config[i]);
       return cookies;
   }
   saveConfig({hello: 'world', foo: 'bar'});
   console.log(document.cookie);
   ```

   ```
   Outputs: hello=world; foo=bar;
   ```

   ---
2. #### One cookie from an object converted to a string

   You can convert the object to a string and store it in one cookie using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

   ```js
   var saveConfig = function(config) {
       return document.cookie = 'config=' + JSON.stringify(config);
   }
   saveConfig({hello: 'world', foo: 'bar'});
   console.log(document.cookie);
   ```

   ```
   Outputs: config={"hello":"world","foo":"bar"};
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In your second "option" you have to send a value for the parameters like this:

```
function(config) {
    var config_copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(config));
    setCookie("key", config_copy);
}
```

if you call it without the parameters, they will have an `undefined` value

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your variables to setCookie() in order for the function to use them.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Calling_functions